# Accessing index in Typescript Interface

Tags: typescript

I have created a Dictionary in Typescript using index types and i'm trying to use it somewhere in my code. But can't figure out how can access the index. I have two interfaces:

```
export interface OrderForm {
 model_id?: number;
 model_color_id?: number;
 model_product_id?: number;
 total_lld: ComputedTotalLLDOptions;
 product_parts_id?: string;
}

export interface ComputedTotalLLDOptions {
  [index: number]: {
    contribution: number;
    duration: number;
    rent: number;
  };
}
```

Do you have some example of how can i use it ?

Comment: Hi, could you please explain how you expect to use these interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces define the shape of a "thing" in your code; they provide static types and no runtime functionality. You can use them to specify the expected type for a variable/parameter/property. An example with your `ComputedTotalLLDOptions`:

```
const foo: ComputedTotalLLDOptions = {
    0: {
        contribution: 1,
        duration: 2,
        rent: 3
    }
}

const bar: number = foo[0].contribution
```

See this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgeSgBM0AxaAWzgG8BYAKDgohIBsB9BIgfgC44kAVwoAjNAG4GTFsA7YIraJx78hoiVOZt2YKC0HYYyvgOFiokxjAgxMHVqyL8AwhAphBqIgBUbdgDL%20ACL4YDAIEEgAzpZwuvqGOpiwUcb8UTBQyADmlgC%20DAygkLCIKGhYuHCu7p7APn6sgSFhEdE0UnAA2sgkIKpmaAC6-HSMcBPyKFkinm0D6hadE0SCUJjhkQvmsRNwUMAo2xrjefmF9AD0l3AAqlF4mFFwmHAAbskImCKseDAAnmBHkgkH5NkgGFMMnB0BAIC43B4vL5bE1gqFwc8ALwdcYTAAMo2We0mkUyCFm4P4AEYADTEkmrdZUuAAJnpeJJ%200OMH4AGZiQV6ELIZFoSJkscoHAcbCIF18UMAHRTcmUtoXa53B4vZ6vdCCJCGNpxZKYCjAVBQXgMA1G8FwbKW0gIKAZVzTClzSIAClhUAo-EIJCg5ADAEpcSSDjA1kgYZQldZUewHEQFcrVTNvUhzvQgA).